# Swift GeoJson Parse

Tags: json, parsing, codable

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      126.9823439963945,
      37.56461982743129
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        126.9823439963945,
        37.56461982743129
      ],
      [
        126.98230789017299,
        37.564453179812105
      ],
      [
        126.98210513804034,
        37.563703265276516
      ],
      [
        126.98207180945346,
        37.56352550784786
      ],
      [
        126.9817857308457,
        37.56284502921221
      ],
      [
        126.98166907678578,
        37.562633941789535
      ],
      [
        126.98157186492477,
        37.56247284870586
      ],
      [
        126.98128300624569,
        37.56205345097403
      ],
      [
        126.98124689891416,
        37.56200067907546
      ]
    ],
    "traffic": [0, 8, 4, 12]
  }}
```

This is what I got.
And I don't have any idea to parse key "coordinates".
This type depends on type of geometry.
If type is "Point", type became [String].
If type is "LineString", type became [[String]].
How can I solve it?

Comment: Does my answer answer your question? If it does, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this cocoa pod: [CodableGeoJSON](https://github.com/guykogus/CodableGeoJSON).

It has the `Codable` structs written up for you. You seem to have a feature with an unknown geometry here, so you can do something like this:

```
let geoJSON = try JSONDecoder().decode(GeoJSON.self, from: geoJSONData)
guard case .feature(let feature) = geoJSON else {
    // the GeoJSON does not contain a feature!
}

// handle each kind of geometry...
switch feature.geometry {
case .point(let coordinates): // coordinates is a GeoJSONPosition
    // ...
case .multiPoint(let coordinates): // coordinates is a [GeoJSONPosition]
    // ...
case .lineString(let coordinates): // coordinates is a [GeoJSONPosition]
    // ...
case .multiLineString(let coordinates): // coordinates is a [[GeoJSONPosition]]
    // ...
case .polygon(let coordinates): // coordinates is a [[GeoJSONPosition]]
    // ...
case .multiPolygon(let coordinates): // coordinates is a [[[GeoJSONPosition]]]
    // ...
case .geometryCollection(let geometries):
    // ...
}
```

If you don't like using a library just for this, have a look at their source code and try to learn from it, specifically, [GeoJSON.swift](https://github.com/guykogus/CodableGeoJSON/blob/master/CodableGeoJSON/GeoJSON.swift).