# JSON parsing data in SWIFTUI

Tags: json, swift

in my very basic code I need get data from JSON. But i get only one value.
i have this input JSON:

```
{
  "features": 
  [
    {
            "geometry":
            {
                    "coordinates": [
                        14.49961,
                        50.03353
                    ],
                    "type": "Point"
            }
        },
        {
            "geometry":
            {
                    "coordinates": [
                        14.4213,
                        50.00144
                    ],
                    "type": "Point"
            }
    }
  ],
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

**and this code in SwiftUI, where i need get all data throw JSON. Value of field "type" work, but rest of field i can't get - what i do wrong?**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import Combine

class fetchResults{
    func getData(completion: @escaping (RequestA) -> ()){
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.golemio.cz/v2/vehiclepositions?limit=2")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-access-token")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode(RequestA.self, from: data!)
            if let response = response {
                
                if let data = data, let body = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                   
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    completion(result)
                                }
                }
            } else {
                print(error ?? "Unknown error")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

struct RequestA: Decodable {
    var features: [Features]!
    var type: String
}

struct Features: Decodable {
    var geometry: Geometry
}

struct Geometry: Decodable {
    var coordinates: [Double]
    var type: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var res = RequestA()
    var body: some View {
        Text(res.type ?? "N/A")           // <<< "res.type" work but "res.features.geometry.coordinates[0] not
                     .onAppear()
                     {
                        fetchResults().getData
                        {(res) in
                            self.res = res    
                        }
                     }
  }
}
```

I will be very glad, if somebody help me a show me, what i do wrong.

Comment: Instead of force unwrapping your `try` you should wrap it in a `do-catch` and print out the error.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but the variant with "res.type" works and the variant "res.features.geometry.coordinates [0]" can't be written at all (Xcode reports error "Value of type [Features] has no member ' This is not an error during program run.

Comment: You need to read up on arrays, since `features` is an array try `List` and/or `ForEach` in your SwiftUI code.

Comment: I think is better as you rector a bit you code, separating network from data. I suggest so make a UNIT test that works fine with data (without burden form networking) and try parsing.

Answer (score 0):

```
res.features.geometry.coordinates
```

res is `RequestA` and a "`RequestA`" has a property `features` which is of type `[Features]` - an array of "Features"

`Array of features` doesn't have a property "`geometry`" so you can't write an expression like `res.features.geometry`

Did you mean for `RequestA` "features" property to be of type `Features` not `[Features]`? Or did you mean to do something for each one of the features in the array, or perhaps the first one etc?

If you're interested in parsing GeoJSON, then see [Swift GeoJson Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63644821/swift-geojson-parse)

Comment: I solved my problem, but I also will read your link. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If someone will solve a similar problem, I solved it like this inside body View:

```
print(res.features![0].geometry.coordinates[0])
```

Karel

Comment: I am a little confused by this answer, you are force unwrapping `features` but there is nothing that is optional in the code in your question.

Comment: Hi Joakim, thanks for your response. It is true, that in question was mistake. For correct topic I was edit that.

Comment: If the property really is optional you should use ? and not ! in that situation. But is it really optional?